# How to access column from other table in calculation?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Sorry for the title. Not really sure how to word it. Edits appreciated.

I have a table, `bin_content`, which has a column, `LotId` that I'm trying to do a calculation on. The calculation is a bit complex, but I've boiled it down to the part that is failing in the sql below:

```
SELECT bc.LotId, bc.ModelId, x.datecode FROM (
    SELECT
        LEFT(bc.LotId,4) as datecode
) x, bin_content bc WHERE bc.Quantity <> 0;
```

When I run this, I'm getting:

> SQL Error (1109): Unknown table 'bc' in field list.

The error is referring to the reference on the third line of code:

```
        LEFT(bc.LotId,4) as datecode
```

I'm wanting to access the value of `LotId` in the current record. What's the right way to do this?

EDIT:

Here's the actual calculation:

```
SELECT bc.LotId, bc.ModelId, x.monthAge FROM (
    SELECT
        @reportdate := CURDATE(),
        @datecode := LEFT(bc.LotId,4),
        @dcyear := CONCAT("20",LEFT(@datecode,2)),
        @dcweek := SUBSTRING(@datecode,3,2),
        @dcyearstart := CONCAT(@dcyear,'-01-01'),
        @firstWeekLength := MOD((8-DAYOFWEEK(@dcyearstart)),7),
        @builddate := ADDDATE(@dcyearstart,IF(@dcweek = 1, 0, @firstWeekLength + (7*(@dcweek-2)))),
        @partialmonth := (DAY(@reportdate) - DAY(@builddate))/31,
        @monthAge := ((YEAR(@reportdate) - @dcyear) * 12) + (MONTH(@reportdate) - MONTH(@builddate)) + @partialmonth as monthAge
) x, bin_content bc WHERE bc.Quantity <> 0;
```

The line below is the problem child:

```
        @datecode := LEFT(bc.LotId,4),
```

If I can get that line to return a value, the rest works. The basic idea is that the `bc.LotId` has a date code in the first four digits (`YYWW`, where `YY`=year, and `WW`=week number). I'm calculating the number of months that have passed since that date code.

Comment: why not just do "SELECT bc.LotId, bc.ModelId, LEFT(bc.LotId,4) as datecode from bin_content bc WHERE bc.Quantity <> 0;"  ?

Comment: Hi, @dbinns66, the calculation is actually much more complex. It involves about 10 assignments, each building on the other. I've simplified it here to this one assignment in the inner SELECT.

Comment: Hi, @Jonathan M, it would really help to show the entire query and explain it as much as possible so those trying to help have as complete an idea of your data and your final goal as possible

Comment: Posted. Sorry for reducing it too far.

Comment: Other than not showing the results of the calculations what purpose does the subquery serve?  How is the bc.LotId in the subquery tying back to the bc.LotId in the main query?

Comment: @dbinns66, you've got it right. The only purpose of the subquery is to give me a place to calculate the value of `monthAge`. I'm new to anything beyond basic queries, so maybe this is not the right way to go about this. The idea is to calculate `monthAge` from `bc.LotId`.

Comment: I'd just move the calculations to the main query as it looks like you'll get incorrect results since you're not tying the subquery to the main query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited answer after the question was updated:

Since you only rely on a single row for this calculation, you can move all the columns to the inner query and select from there:

```
SELECT  x.LotId, 
        x.ModelId, 
        x.monthAge 
FROM    (SELECT  bc.LotId, 
                 bc.ModelId,
                 @reportdate := CURDATE(),
                 @datecode := LEFT(bc.LotId,4),
                 @dcyear := CONCAT("20",LEFT(@datecode,2)),
                 @dcweek := SUBSTRING(@datecode,3,2),
                 @dcyearstart := CONCAT(@dcyear,'-01-01'),
                 @firstWeekLength := MOD((8-DAYOFWEEK(@dcyearstart)),7),
                 @builddate := ADDDATE(@dcyearstart,IF(@dcweek = 1, 0, @firstWeekLength + (7*(@dcweek-2)))),
                 @partialmonth := (DAY(@reportdate) - DAY(@builddate))/31,
                 @monthAge := ((YEAR(@reportdate) - @dcyear) * 12) + (MONTH(@reportdate) - MONTH(@builddate)) + @partialmonth as monthAge
         FROM    bin_content bc
         WHERE   bc.Quantity <> 0) x
```

Comment: The calculation is actually much more complex. It involves about 10 assignments, each building on the other. I've simplified it here to this one assignment in the inner SELECT. Would it be helpful for me to just post the actual calculation?

Comment: @JonathanM yes please. I'm all for [MCVEs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I'm afraid you've over-simplified it to the extend of losing the issue you're trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry about that. Posted.

Comment: Hmm. The delay I mentioned (in the comment I've now deleted) must have been something on my client, because now it is running quite fast without modification.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because `bin_content` is not in the scope of your subquery.

Removing a lot of the code, you have a skeleton like this:

```
SELECT stuff
FROM(
   SELECT stuff
) x, bin_content bc...
```

There is no `FROM` clause inside your inner select query, so `bc` cannot be referenced. The query is complex, so I'm not sure if making it like this will work:

```
SELECT stuff
FROM(
   SELECT stuff
   FROM bin_content bc
) x, bin_content bc...
```

but the issue is definitely as a result of `bc` not being in the proper scope.

Comment: This seems to be in the right direction, but how do I ensure the record in the subquery is the same one as the main query?

Comment: Perhaps you can just move the bin_content table into the subquery, and then select what you need from that? I think @mureinik's answer handles this very well.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help:

```
SELECT bc.LotId, bc.ModelId, x.datecode FROM (
    SELECT LEFT(bc2.LotId,4) as datecode
    From bin_content bc2 
    WHERE bc2.LotId = bc.LotId
) x, bin_content bc WHERE bc.Quantity <> 0;
```

Update : I think why this will not work in you case?

```
SELECT bc.LotId, bc.ModelId, LEFT(bc.LotId,4) as datecode 
From bin_content bc WHERE bc.Quantity <> 0;
```

Comment: Ah, nice. I see now how to ensure the two records match.

Comment: You are welcome but I am wondering why you are using a sub-qery! see my update

Comment: Yes, see the full query in the EDIT to my post. It's much more complex. I'm just using a subquery to hide some of the calculated values that, while helpful, don't need to be seen.